# Php CLI gives no output in terminal OSX

Tags: php, macos

I have a simple php script: testfile.php:

```
<?php
echo 'testing';
?>
```

When I try to execute it via terminal using 'php testfile.php', I get no output whatsoever.  Trying to run files that don't exist produces the expected error message, but this command returns nothing at all. I suspect it's a permissions issue, but I'm not sure what the permissions should be. Help!?

Comment: You need to use the -f flag Edit: weirdly enough "If none of -r -f -B -R -F -E or -S is present but a single parameter is
       given then this parameter is taken as the filename to parse and execute
       (same as with -f). If no parameter is present then the standard input is
       read and executed."

Comment: Do you have apache? I don't think PHP will execute in OSX without some kind of server setup.

Comment: @Wakka It will/would.

Comment: What does `php -r "echo 'test';"` produce?

Comment: @user3783243, It wont without some kind of server setup.

Comment: @Wakka The CLI PHP doesn't require apache. If `php` is defined to route to apache directive maybe, `/usr/bin/php` shouldn't involved apache though. `which php` should show that

Comment: php -r "echo 'test';" also produces nothing in the terminal!  *sigh*.  And yes, I have apache and php installed.  And, in response to Spoody, php -f testfile.php also produces nothing.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling PHP? What is the output of `php -v`?

Comment: Does `which php` give a result?